# Android public movies directory is empty even though it isn't

Tags: android

I am very frustrated with Android right now.

I'm trying to access files in the directory defined by `Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES`:

[image: debug]

As you can see from the debug information it is a directory and the path is `/storage/emulated/0/Movies`. But it doesn't contain any files.

If I use the adb shell to list the files in the directory I get this result:

[image: adb shell output]

So clearly there **are** files in that directory. I thought it might be a permission issue, so I added these to my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Still the same result though. What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: "But it doesn't contain any files" -- what do you mean by this? Do you mean that `listFiles()` is returning an erroneous value? Do you mean that when you look at this directory in your desktop OS's file explorer (via attaching the device over a USB cable), you are not seeing the files? Do you mean something else?

Comment: I mean that `movieFolder.listFiles()` returns null. According to the [File documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) it should do that if `movieFolder` is not a directory - but it is.

Comment: Furthermore, I expect `listFiles()` to return `null` or a zero length array if a directory does not contain any files, which is why I wrote "But it doesn't contain any files".

Comment: Make sure that your manifest entries are in the proper spots. Also, if you are testing this on Android 6.0, and your `targetSdkVersion` is 23+, you need to request those permissions at runtime. See https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/31/hey-where-did-my-permission-go.html

Comment: Implementing run time permission request worked, thank you. Please post this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact repercussions of missing an Android 6.0 runtime permission vary. Usually, you get a `SecurityException`, and that's a clearer indication of what's going on, since the exception message tells you what you are missing.

In this case, apparently the Java file I/O stuff eats the `SecurityException`, or such an exception is not raised, which is why you were getting odd values back from `listFiles()`.

Your options are either to drop back below `targetSdkVersion 23` or implement the ask-the-user-for-permission logic (e.g., `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`).